# Nextjs Script tag not working ReferenceError: alertShow is not defined

Tags: next.js

I tried soo many time with different ways but it is showing the same error please guide me.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <h1>hii</h1>
      <button onClick={alertShow}>Click Me</button>
      <Script src='../public/test.js'></Script>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The error is weird, can you show the contents of test.js?

Comment: function alertShow(){
    alert('you clicked me')
}

Comment: Actually iam including external js file in my main project but iam facing this error then I wrote this simple function to test this is working or not but it is not working.

Comment: try this when calling Script:  <Script src="/test.js" />

Comment: no sir not working

Comment: Call your allert inside the test.js file. Like this: function alertShow() { alert('you clicked me'); }
alertShow();

Comment: no it is showing same error

Comment: I did a bit of research and posted the answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

You can see something simillar in the [logs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/third-party-javascript) This is how I did it:

test.js file:

```
window.alertShow = { myAlert: () => { alert('you clicked me'); } };
```

MyAppFile:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp() {
  const [scriptAlert, setScriptAlert] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="/test.js"
        onLoad={() => {
          setScriptAlert(window.alertShow);
        }}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => scriptAlert && scriptAlert.myAlert()}>Click Me</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Did this work? @Nikhil verma

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to get around the error like this:

```js
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `<button onclick="alertShow()">Click me</button>`
  }}
/>
```

In this case `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is safe because we are passing a hard coded value.